# Connect Processing with SQL database and Get name of columns

Tags: mysql, processing

I have connect Processing and SQL by using database library "de.Bezier.data.sql".
I don't know How can I get the name of columns in a specific Table.
I get the correct name of database, but i got the following as result of name of columns "Tables_in_sql7363100"

```
import de.bezier.data.sql.*;

MySQL sql;
String[] tableNames;
String[] columnNames;

void setup() {
  size(300, 300);
  database_connection();

  if (connect) {
    tableNames = sql.getTableNames();
    for (int i=0; i<tableNames.length; i++) {
      println(tableNames[i]);
    }
 
    columnNames = sql.getColumnNames();
    for (int i=0; i<ColumnNames.length; i++) {
      println(columnNames[i]);
    }
  }
}

void draw() {
  background(255);
}



void database_connection() {
  sql = new MySQL(this, "ServerName", "DataBase", "DUN", "PW");
  if (sql.connect()) {
    connect = true;
    connect_status = "Conected";
  } else {
    connect = false;
    connect_status = "Connection Failed";
  }
}
```

Comment: Will you always use a local database or is it possible that latency becomes an issue later?

Comment: No .. I'm not using local database, I'm connecting to database online

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 problems with what I'm seeing. The first one, which interests you, is that you didn't select any table. That's why you don't get a list of columns. You can fix this by using a simple query:

```
sql.query("SELECT * FROM myTable");
```

But that's not the only thing: you're not accounting for lag. It may work for now on a local database because lag is really low, but this won't fly with something which is over the internet. Here's an example where I show columns from a public test database and how long it takes to get the result from my query back:

```
import de.bezier.data.sql.*;

MySQL sql;
String user = "rfamro";
String pass = "";
String server = "mysql-rfam-public.ebi.ac.uk:4497";
String database = "Rfam";

String[] columnNames;

void setup() {
  size(300, 300);
  sql = new MySQL(this, server, database, user, pass);
}

void draw() {
  if (columnNames != null) {
    println("It took " + millis() + "ms to get this data back.");
    for (String s : columnNames) {
      println(s);
    }
    noLoop();
  } else if (sql.connect()) {
    sql.query("SELECT * FROM family");
    sql.next();  // only use .next when you know you have data
    columnNames = sql.getColumnNames();
  }
}
```

From here, it takes between 2-7 seconds to get the data back. You'll understand that, the `setup()` method running taking about a couple milliseconds, you won't have any results back by then.

Hope this helps. Have fun!

Comment: Thanks .. That's useful.
However, In general I need to write a command to SQL and get back the results
For example, If I want to write query "SHOW DATABASES;" and would like to get the results of this command. 
Is there any way in general to pass query to SQL and see the results.